# How to convert `git:` urls to `http:` urls

Tags: git, proxy

I'm working behind an http proxy. I'm trying to clone Android's source tree using their "repo" tool.

This tool insists on using `git://` URLs, even though `http://` URLs also work. As a result, I can't download the source.

Is it possible to force `git` to always use `http`?

***Edit:*** my http_proxy is configured correctly. For example, this works:

```
git clone http://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

But this doesn't (errno=Connection timed out):

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy/397642#397642) does not really help me.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Here's an example of rewriting the default protocol for GitHub:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

The exact values depend on the protocol in use. For example, the above command for git over ssh will look like:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Git documentation for [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

> `git config [--global] url.<base>.insteadOf <other_url>`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with `<base>`. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.

Comment: helps when firewall blocks git protocol! :)

Comment: Can I ask a question here? I was using this but wrote "heeps" rather than "https". How can I correct this? Does 'git config --global.url.https://github.com/.insteadOf heeps://github.com/' work?

Comment: Tip: `git remote -v` immediately shows effect of `insteadOf` and `pushInsteadOf` configs

Comment: This worked for me in public WiFi with blocked 22 port. How config can be reverted to defaults?

Comment: This answer almost made it for me, except my repository was using a
`git@github.com:...` format for the urls. This worked: `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf 'git@github.com:'` for me.

Comment: Thanks! this works on this error ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: I'm getting error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value

Comment: Thanks! Exact solution, worked for me I was getting this error: 

"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/shahata/jsdelivr-cdn-data.git

Answer (score 35):

I don't know how this [repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=tools/repo.git) tool uses Git (and if you can configure 'repo' to use http protocol), but you can try to trick it using `url.<base>.insteadOf` configuration variable (see [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and [git-fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) manpages).

Have you tried to use `core.gitProxy` to pass through firewall, if it is the problme with using git protocol?

Comment: Thanks, this "insteadOf" variable is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 27):

I had this same problem with recursively getting submodules in a git repository.  I'm behind a crazy firewall that doesn't allow outgoing connections on the git port.  Some of the submodules of the submodules were coded as `git://github.com/blah/blah.git`.  This killed my recursive population of submodules.  The workaround is the following:

```
git config --global url."https://<GITUSERNAME>@".insteadOf git://
```

This replaces `git://` with `https://<GITUSERNAME>@` in all submodule repository URLs.  You need to replace `<GITUSERNAME>` with your own git username.  Also note that the `--global` is required; just adding this configuration to the base repository directory doesn't work.

Comment: Y not just use

git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

as shown here? 
https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/141

I mean is the username mandatory?

Answer (score 4):

You can verify in `~/.gitconfig` if you're overwriting SSH with https://, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Find your git account's git config file(.gitconfig), modify the followings:

```
    [user]
    email = your e-mail account


    name = your git account
    [url "git@github.com:"]


    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```