# Error - 'bower install' fail with Exit Status 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

While walking through the [angular-phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), I came across the following error immediately after running the `npm install` command:

[image]

I looked in the log file, too, but it more or less repeats the same error message shown in the console. What am I missing?

Comment: it looks like a network connection problem. would you please run command `git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git`? it should list all tags

Comment: @shawnzhu - When I ran the command, I got `fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error` Is this error caused by Github's end (unlikely, I'd think) or mine?

Comment: Might be a routing problem between your location and github. I have no problem reaching github. Can you browse http://github.com ?

Comment: @TimothyStrimple - Yes, I have no problem browsing github.com

Comment: Have you tried the solution that Timothy and I gave?

Comment: Problem solved! Now I'm torn between whose answer to accept. Both answers are equally valid but Tim came to my rescue a bit faster, so...

Comment: You could always upvote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're behind some network proxy or firewall that restricts the ports you can access. In this case, you can tell git to use https:// instead of git:// for cloning. Answer is based off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/git-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls).

`git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

Answer (score 4):

Try making git use an http connection rather than a git one like so:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Sometimes the git protocol is blocked, but the https one won't be.

A similar issue is referenced [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/141)

Comment: Your answer is just as good as Tim's but I had to accept his answer as he came to my rescue a bit sooner. Thank you for taking time to answer (upvote for you).

Comment: Casp, I hear you. Cheers! :)