# How to use Go with a private GitLab repo

Tags: git, go, get, package, gitlab

GitLab is a free, open-source way to host private `.git` repositories but it does not seem to work with Go. When you create a project it generates a URL of the form:

```
git@1.2.3.4:private-developers/project.git
```

where:

- `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of the gitlab server
- `private-developers` is a user group which has access to the private repo

Golang 1.2.1 doesn't seem to understand this syntax.

```
go get git@1.2.3.4:private-developers/project.git
```

results in:

```
package git@23.251.148.129/project.git: unrecognized import path "git@1.2.3.4/project.git"
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: that's not how `go get` works, it uses import paths, not direct scm uris. Does your gitlab have https git access (like github)?

Comment: I'm not sure. It was installed via this procedure: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gitlab/ . Is there a way i can tell?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with gitlab, but I know they added support for `go get` on public projects: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5958. Worst case you can always just do the initial clone of the repo into your GOPATH manually

Comment: regrettably i have to use a private repo for this. I am using the 'worst case' for now :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue is now resolved in Gitlab 8.* but is still unintuitive. The most difficult challenge indeed is `go get` and the following steps will allow you to overcome those:

1. Create an SSH key pair. Be sure to not overwrite an existing pair that is by default saved in `~/.ssh/`.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
   ```
2. Create a new *Secret Variable* in your Gitlab project. Use `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` as *Key* and the content of your *private* key as *Value*.
3. Modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` with a `before_script`.

   ```
   before_script:
     # install ssh-agent if not already installed
     - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
     # run ssh-agent
     - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
     # add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
     - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
     # for Docker builds disable host key checking
     - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
     - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
   ```
4. Add the *public* key from the key pair created in step 1 as a *Deploy Key* in the project that you need to `go get`.

Comment: regrettably i can't verify that this works as I'm not currently using gitlab. If someone can verify this i'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @JamesFremen, I don't know that anyone will jump on it but I've had several people ask me about it and it seems to work well.

Comment: This worked for me after I added one more line to the `before_script` section: `- git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"`

Answer (score 45):

Run this command:

```
git config --global url."git@1.2.3.4:".insteadOf "https://1.2.3.4/"
```

Assuming you have the correct privileges to `git clone` the repository, this will make `go get` work for **all** repos on server `1.2.3.4`.

I tested this with go version 1.6.2, 1.8, and 1.9.1.

Comment: simply does not work

Answer (score 25):

Easiest way with Gitlab

```
before_script:
  - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
  - go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}
```

See more details here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#dependent-repositories

Comment: This does indeed work, and it is very clean. The only issue here is that this documentation link is broken . 

I was able to find these: 

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html 

They define the available environment vars, and the one for `CI_JOB_TOKEN` has an example for a clone command that uses the same url with the username:token syntax as you see here. This example followed the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383587/4430821 to create the `git config` command.

Comment: This must be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

GitLab version 11.8+ and Go version 1.13+ will work with BASIC auth by using your GitLab personal token.
Go to Settings -> Access Tokens in your Gitlab, add a personal access token or use your existing one.
In your ~/.netrc file, add following lines:

```
machine <your GitLab domain> (e.g. gitlab.com)
login <your GitLab id>
password <your GitLab personal access token>
```

Then you should be able to do go get locally.

If you need to build it in CI, then add following line in your .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
before_script:
    - echo -e "machine <your GitLab domain>\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
```

Answer (score 7):

If `go get` can't fetch the repo, you can always do the initial clone with git directly:

```
git clone git@gitlab:private-developers/project.git $GOPATH/src/gitlab/private-developers/project
```

The tools will then work normally, expect for `go get -u` which will require the `-f` flag because the git remote doesn't match the canonical import path.

Comment: yes, i think this is the workaround i'm currently using.

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab does support `go get` natively.

`go get` will issue an http request to the url you provide and look for meta tags that point to the exact source control path.

For my gitlab installation this is `mygitlabdomain.com/myProject/myRepo`. For you I assume this would be `1.2.3.4/private-developers/project`.

Unfortunately it only appears to give the http scm path, not the ssh path, so I had to enter my credentials to clone. You can easily fiddle with the remote in your local repository after it clones if you want to update to the ssh url.

You can test the url by poking `http://1.2.3.4:private-developers/project?go-get=1` and viewing source and looking for the meta tag.

Comment: I've posted an answer as well.. it seems like a fix is in gitlab 7.9.

Comment: thanks for all the help.. hopefully this is working smoothly in the near future

Answer (score 3):

From [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) version 5.2, `dep` supports private repositories for Gitlab private repositories.

On [.netrc](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-netrc.html) file, you can provide your Gitlab username and access token for accessing private repositories.

1. Create `.netrc` file in your $HOME directory

```sh
$ touch $HOME/.netrc
```

2. Edit your `.netrc` with your Gitlab credentials

```
machine gitlab.<private>.com
login <gitlab-username>
password <gitlab-access-token>

... (more private repositories if needed)
```

3. In your Go repository, run the `dep` command to resolve private packages. In this case,

```
$ dep ensure -v
```

Comment: Creating the .netrc file resolved my issue in my ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

The way I usually do it is:

Ensure you are using SSH.

once that's done you can configure your git to use `ssh` instead `https`

If you are using Mac OX. you can run vim ~/.gitconfig
and add

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

once configured you can run

```
GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/your_username_or_group" go get gitlab.com/name_or_group/repo_name
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For HTTPS private gitlab repo, @Rick Smith's answer is enough. Here's a compensation for HTTP repo, first run the command:

```
git config --global url."git@mygitlab.com:".insteadOf "http://mygitlab.com/"
```

then use below `go get` command to get the golang project:

```
go get -v  -insecure  mygitlab.com/user/repo
```

Comment: At this time, go: -insecure flag is no longer supported; use GOINSECURE instead

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this works outside of go using gitlab 7.3.2 and, as JimB has observed, can be used as a workaround. I find that i do get prompted for username/password, even though an SSH key is registered with gitlab:

```bash
git clone http://1.2.3.4/private-developers/project.git
```

Alternatively i can use the SSH equivalent which, since i have an SSH key registered with gitlab, avoids the prompts:

```bash
git clone git@1.2.3.4:private-developers/project.git
```

Neither works with go currently. A fix may be in 7.9 but i haven't had a chance to test it:
[upcoming bugfix](http://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8949)

Comment: Just a heads up. Although the bug was closed, the issue still remains.

Comment: @JamesFreman I'm on gitlab 8.2, and still getting http urls. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your git credentials and Go will use them:

1. generate a unique password on your github (somewhere in settings).
2. `git config credential.helper store`
3. `echo https://your-github-username:your-generated-password@github.com >> ~/.git-credentials`
4. profit.

Comment: He is talking about gitlab, not github. Gitlab is an open source project for private repository hosting.