# mac does not appear to be a git repository miss a slash

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, clone

I

```
git clone -v https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git /Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover
```

It fail.

```
git clone https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git
Cloning into 'discover'...
fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but if I

```
git clone https://github.com/xormplus/xorm.git
```

it works.

I don't know why it miss a "/" int the git url .

and if I

```
git clone git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git
```

it works,because I have already add my mac rsa_pub into the gitlab and I can always git clone success with this format

```
 git clone git@test.example.cc:anything/project.
```

The reason I ask this question it that I use go get  and it return error

```
bogon:Taotie Macbook$   go get test.example.cc/Taotie/discover
# cd .; git clone https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git /Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover
Cloning into '/Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover'...
fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
package test.example.cc/Taotie/discover: exit status 128
```

Finally `git config --global url."git@test.example.cc:".insteadOf "https://test.example.cc/"` solved my problem~~~

Comment: What if you do: `cd /Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie && git clone https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git discover` ?

Comment: "fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository" This is a syntax related to cloning with SSH. Could you elaborate more on the commands you wrote?

Comment: @SajibKhan I do as you say ,then I get the same error                   
bogon:Taotie Macbook$ git clone https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git 
  discover
Cloning into 'discover'...
fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Try if this work `git clone https://test.example.cc\/Taotie/discover.git discover` ?

Comment: @SajibKhan It fails too.                                                                                   
 ```bogon:Taotie Macbook$ git clone https://test.example.cc\/Taotie/discover.git discover
Cloning into 'discover'...
fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.```

Comment: @Oren_C I just  ```go get test.example.cc/Taotie/discover```  or ```git clone -v https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git /Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover
```under manbookpro - macOS Mojave 10.14.2 - bash,and it fails .What information do you need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clone a private GitLab repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202642/how-can-i-clone-a-private-gitlab-repository)

Comment: Try this: `git clone https://test.example.cc%2FTaotie/discover.git discover`

Comment: @SajibKhan ```fatal: unable to access 'https://test.example.cc%2FTaotie/discover.git/': Could not resolve host: test.example.cc%2FTaotie```

Comment: Possbile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707689/how-to-use-golang-with-a-private-gitlab-repo

Comment: @Baklap4 Bingo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Oren_C said:

> "fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository" This is a syntax related to cloning with SSH.

You're cloning with SSH that being said and the repo exists, the only option left would be that you didn't add a SSH public key to your git instance.

You can copy it from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

## Edit

OP had used a wrongly url. The fix was to use:
`git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git` Note the `:` between host and repo instead of `/`

## Edit 2

To clone the repo into your given directory use the following command:

```
git clone git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git /Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover
```

This will clone the repo in the given directory: `/Users/Macbook/go/src/test.example.cc/Taotie/discover`.

## last edit

To clone it with Golang you should add a configuration:

```
git config --global url."git@test.example.cc:".insteadOf "https://test.example.cc/"
```

This replaces the generated git url to be formatted correctly in the form of: `git@host.tld/name/repo.git`

Then just run `go get https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git`

Comment: I have already add my ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into gitlab and                                                   git clone git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git
  always work.Now I am trying to google something about "syntax related to cloning with SSH"  ~_~

Comment: Something strange happens if I ```git clone -v https://test.example.cc///////////Taotie/discover.git 
``` and the error is the same ```Cloning into 'discover'...
fatal: 'git@test.example.ccTaotie/discover.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```

Comment: instead of using the `https` url can you use the git url? `git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git` note the `:` instead of `/`. Full command should be `git clone git@test.example.cc:Taotie/discover.git` This will clone the repo in your current folder.

Comment: awesome, Updated the answer with the solution. Feel free to mark it as an answer

Comment: em......my real problem have not yet been solved,Because as I mention on my question upon ,It is because I want to use go get test.example.cc/Taotie/discover and then go get transfer it into ```cd .; git clone https://test.example.cc/Taotie/discover.git ...``` and it fails at the end.So even I can git clone git@xxx ,but I can't use go get to get private repos.and If I can't use go get ,things that related to lib dependent will make me crazy.

Comment: Updated the answer with the cloning into a given directory.

Comment: Updated answer to support the golang question which wasn't provided upon answering

Comment: ```git config --global url."git@test.example.cc:".insteadOf "https://test.example.cc/"``` solved my problem ,thanks.