# Packages cannot be installed in my Mac with the Bower

Tags: node.js, git, macos, bower

I am using the Terminal 2.6 on the Mac OS X.11.1.  And NPM, Git and Bower are already installed to it as follows:

- $ npm --version
  2.14.7
- $ git --version
  git version 2.6.2
- $ bower --version
  1.6.5

But when I tried to install a package, for example jQuery with the command, "bower install jquery", the error below was indicated.  And the package failed to be installed.

> $ bower install jquery
>   bower jquery#*    not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
>   bower jquery#*    resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
>   bower jquery#*    ECMDERR Failed to
>   execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
>   git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable
>   to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]:
>   errno=Connection refused
>
> Additional error details:
>   fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection refused

What this kind of error would be caused by?  Or how could I investigate causes of the error?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: convert "git" urls to "http" urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/git-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls)

Comment: Have you uploaded your public ssh key to github?

Comment: Thank you all for your advices.  The problem was not caused by installation of the Bower.  Our network administrator changed some settings of the server and the tool has worked correctly.  I am not sure its detail though.