# Visual Studio - Git clone fails over SSH, but works over HTTPS

Tags: windows, git, github, clone

I am using a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.1), and Git tools.
When I try to clone an existing GitHub repository, either by using the commandline tools, or by using git tools, I receive the following error message:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I believe this error is caused by SSH and I cannot seem to make git use HTTPS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383587/3058302)? It may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert \`git:\` urls to \`http:\` urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/how-to-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls)

Comment: thanks mangu that post seems to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using 2-factor authentication at GitHub**

You must either do one of the following:

1. Use the SSH link, add an SSH key to your GitHub account and load it using the SSH agent in Windows, this may be done using Putty.
2. [Generate a personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new), and use the HTTPS link. Use your GitHub username as the username, but use the generated access token as your password.

**If you want to clone any repository using https**

Simply clone it using the HTTPS-link instead of the SSH link. You can find both links here, by clicking on *Use SSH*, you can switch to the SSH link:

[image: SSH link]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to delete ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, so that a new one will be made next time you access git over ssh.