# How to configure rebar3 to fetch dependencies from another host?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I have an app which uses `rebar3`, eg `cowboy`.

My question is: how can I easily configure it to fetch `cowboy` from another host? I would like to switch from `github.com` to my own host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build [cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy) that has two dependencies which are git repositories on GitHub (https://github.com/ninenines/cowlib and https://github.com/ninenines/ranch to be specific). But you want to fetch the repositories from some other host, like your company's own git server where you mirrored all public repositories you need.

You have a number of options:

- Fork cowboy and change the dependency URL-s in the `rebar.config`. This is the only (sane) way I know to make *Rebar3* fetch the dependencies from a different location. The other options will target the layers *below Rebar3* to achieve the same result.
- Configure git to rewrite GitHub URL-s to URL-s on your server, following e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383587/9015322

```
git config --global url.https://git.mycompany.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

- Add an `/etc/hosts` entry that resolves github.com to the IP of your server. You'll probably have to create a fake self-signed certificate for github.com, and make git on the build machine trust it. But you can do that following the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543283/9015322

Answer (score 1):

By default, `rebar3` will only grab packages from either hex.pm, any git repository, or any mercurial repository. You can see your options [here](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dependencies).

If these defaults are not enough for you, you can [create your own dependency resources](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/custom-dep-resources). This will require you to write some Erlang code in order to tell `rebar3` how to find and download the package(s) you are trying to use.