# The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported

Tags: git, github, deployment, github-actions

I have been using github actions for quite sometime but today my deployments started failing. Below is the error from github action logs

```
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/adobe-webplatform/eve.git
Directory: /home/runner/work/stackstream-fe/stackstream-fe
Output:
fatal: remote error: 
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
```

Upon investigation, it appears that below section in my yml file is causing the issue.

```
    - name: Installing modules
      run: yarn install
```

I have looked into [this change log](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github) but can't seem to comprehend the issue.

Additional Details:
Server: **EC2 Instance**
Github actions steps:

```
  steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - id: vars
    run: |
      if [ '${{ github.ref }}' == 'refs/heads/master' ]; then echo "::set-output name=environment::prod_stackstream" ; echo "::set-output name=api-url::api" ; elif [ '${{ github.ref }}' == 'refs/heads/staging' ]; then echo "::set-output name=environment::staging_stackstream"  ; echo "::set-output name=api-url::stagingapi" ; else echo "::set-output name=environment::dev_stackstream" ; echo "::set-output name=api-url::devapi" ; fi

  - uses: pCYSl5EDgo/cat@master
    id: slack
    with:
      path: .github/workflows/slack.txt

  - name: Slack Start Notification
    uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
      ENVIRONMENT: '`${{ steps.vars.outputs.environment }}`'
      COLOR: good
      STATUS: '`Started`'
    with:
      status: custom
      fields: workflow,job,commit,repo,ref,author,took
      custom_payload: |
        ${{ steps.slack.outputs.text }}

  - name: Installing modules
    env:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: 'https://${{ steps.vars.outputs.api-url }}mergestack.com/api/v1'
    run: yarn install

  - name: Create Frontend Build
    env:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: 'https://${{ steps.vars.outputs.api-url }}mergestack.com/api/v1'
    run: yarn build

  - name: Deploy to Frontend Server DEV
    if: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'dev') }}
    uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@v2.1.5
    env:
      SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEV_KEY }}
      ARGS: '-rltgoDzvO --delete'
      SOURCE: 'deploy/'
      REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.DEV_HOST }}
      REMOTE_USER: plyfolio-dev
      TARGET: '/home/plyfolio-dev/${{ steps.vars.outputs.environment }}/fe/deploy'
```

**package.json** file

```
   {
  "name": "stackstream-fe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "fayyaznofal@gmail.com"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.5.0",
    "@lourenci/react-kanban": "^2.1.0",
    "@redux-saga/simple-saga-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@toast-ui/react-chart": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@vtaits/react-color-picker": "^0.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.23.1",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "axios-progress-bar": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "components": "^0.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.16",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "metismenujs": "^1.2.1",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.3.9",
    "npm": "^7.6.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.14.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-auth-code-input": "^1.0.0",
    "react-avatar": "^3.10.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-editable": "^0.8.2",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.3",
    "react-chartist": "^0.14.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.7.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.1",
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-cropper": "^2.1.4",
    "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.8",
    "react-date-picker": "^8.0.6",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-drag-listview": "^0.1.8",
    "react-drawer": "^1.3.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-dual-listbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.10.6",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.15.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.16",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.0.5",
    "react-meta-tags": "^1.0.1",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.6",
    "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
    "react-number-format": "^4.7.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
    "react-rating-tooltip": "^1.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.11",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
    "react-super-responsive-table": "^5.2.0",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-table": "^7.6.3",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "react-toastr": "^3.0.0",
    "react-twitter-auth": "0.0.13",
    "reactstrap": "^8.8.1",
    "recharts": "^2.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.0",
    "styled": "^1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^4.15.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "lint-staged": "^10.1.3",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && mv build ./deploy/build",
    "build-local": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**[package-lock.json](https://gist.github.com/nofalfayyaz/ae2ceeda8d61af19a2ab6c45f80822a7)**

Comment: Am I wrong or is this going to be a huge issue for *many* yocto project layers..

Comment: The linked article states 'We expect very few people are still using this protocol, especially given that you can’t push (it’s read-only on GitHub).' which is weird. They should be able to see the amount of traffic on that protocol right? Meanwhile, a part of the world is burning because they didn't change the protocol in time. Luckily, the fix is relatively easy (https:// instead of git://).

Comment: @Mixxiphoid They (GitHup) might have missed al the indirect dependencies pulled by projects, and those indirect dependencies could still include some `git://` URLs.

Comment: @Logan I think impact is going to be big. In my case I wasn't using any package which was directly causing issue. There was 4th tier dependency which was causing the issue. I was using ```@toast-ui/react-chart```, below was my dependency tree
```eve --> raphael --> tui-chart --> @toast-ui/react-chart``` and ```eve``` was causing issue.

Comment: So, I think there are going to be many people with this sort of dependencies in their project.

Comment: @Logan: There was a 4-month warning. The entire Internet has been moving away from un-authenticated, un-encrypted protocols for a decade, it's not like this is a huge surprise. Personally, I consider it less an "issue" and more "detecting unmaintained dependencies". Plus, this is still only the brownout period, so the protocol will only be disabled for a short period of time, allowing developers to discover the problem. The permanent shutdown is not until March.

Comment: 4-months to whom and where I wonder, first I've heard of it is this post!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**@toast-ui/react-chart** dependency is causing issue for you here.

If you look closely inside your package-lock.json you can backtrack **eve** to **@toast-ui/react-chart**

**eve** --> **raphael** --> **tui-chart** --> **@toast-ui/react-chart**

You can follow this same technique to find any more issues inside your project.

Comment: Thanks @ahmad faraz. Yes, indeed this was the issue. There was some dependency in my package.json file which was in turn using some dependency which was basically causing the issue with github latest upgrade.
I didn't needed that specific dependency so I just removed it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 112):

First, this error message is indeed expected on Jan. 11th, 2022.
See "[Improving Git protocol security on GitHub](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#no-more-unauthenticated-git)".

> January 11, 2022  Final brownout.
>
> This is the full brownout period where we’ll temporarily stop accepting the deprecated key and signature types, ciphers, and MACs, and the unencrypted Git protocol.
> This will help clients discover any lingering use of older keys or old URLs.

Second, check your `package.json` dependencies for any `git://` URL, as in [this example](https://github.com/che-incubator/che-workspace-telemetry-client/blob/6c2261e7b19d95dcbc77f4fff82b7ab059dcc8bf/javascript/src/typescript/package.json#L24), fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/che-incubator/che-workspace-telemetry-client/pull/76/files).

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663523/the-unauthenticated-git-protocol-on-port-9418-is-no-longer-supported/70663683#comment124950610_70663523) by [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag):

> There was a 4-month warning.
> The entire Internet has been moving away from unauthenticated, unencrypted protocols for a decade, it's not like this is a huge surprise.
>
> Personally, I consider it less an "issue" and more "detecting unmaintained dependencies".
>
> Plus, this is still only the brownout period, so the protocol will only be disabled for a short period of time, allowing developers to discover the problem.
>
> The permanent shutdown is not until March 15th.

---

### For GitHub Actions:

As in [actions/checkout issue 14](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/14#issuecomment-523916396), you can add as a first step:

```yaml
    - name: Fix up git URLs
      run: echo -e '[url "https://github.com/"]\n  insteadOf = "git://github.com/"' >> ~/.gitconfig
```

That will change any `git://github.com/` into `https://github.com/`.

### For local projects

For all your repositories, you can set:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

---

You can also use SSH, but [GitHub Security](https://twitter.com/GitHubSecurity/status/1503752147527258116) reminds us that, as of March 15th, 2022, GitHub stopped accepting DSA keys. RSA keys uploaded after Nov 2, 2021 will work only with SHA-2 signatures.
The deprecated MACs, ciphers, and unencrypted Git protocol are permanently disabled.

So this (with the right key) would work:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

That will change any `git://github.com/` (unencrypted Git protocol) into `git@github.com:` (SSH URL).

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I did check the package.json and package-lock.json but there is no dependency using git:// .

Comment: @monofal Maybe an indirect dependencies then. If possible, you should set up an insteadOf Git setting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383587/6309

Comment: @monofal Example: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/14#issuecomment-523916396

Comment: Shall I use this for git submodules

Comment: @sejn Yes, that would work for submodule URL too.

Answer (score 77):

Try using the following command before install:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

P.S. or better ( thanks @bgraves )

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Comment: Works! Avoids having to wait for repos to update.

Comment: better use the reduced version `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/`

Answer (score 19):

Try using https://github.com instead of git://github.com

Comment: This is the simplest and most effective method.

Comment: @BuffMcBigHuge one that I already [mentioned in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70663683/6309), used in the context of a GitHub Action yaml, since the question is about GitHub Action.

Comment: This is exactly what GitHub recommends in [their blog post](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#git-protocol-troubleshooting). You could improve your answer by citing this semi-official resource as justification for the correctness and suitability of your proposed solution.

Answer (score 8):

> I hope this answer would provide more context omitted in the other answers.

Git can use [four protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) to transfer data:

- Local (not relevant here)
- (Smart) HTTP - runs over standard HTTPS ports, and can use various HTTP authentication mechanisms (e.g. username/password) **if authentication is required**. This protocol allows you to provide both read and write access using the same URL; if authentication is required, the server will prompt the client.
- Secure Shell (SSH) - authenticated workflow where both reads and writes are authenticated. It does not support unauthenticated (i.e. anonymous) access. Users need to generate an SSH key pair (containing a private and public key) locally and upload their public key to the server.
- Git protocol - unencrypted and unauthenticated. There is a [Git Daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) that runs on the Git server that listens on port `9418` and services requests.

Each of the protocols uses different URLs:

- Local:

  - Absolute path (e.g. `/srv/git/project.git`)
  - Absolute path prefixed with `file://` protocol (e.g. `file:///srv/git/project.git`)
- HTTP: `https://example.com/gitproject.git`
- SSH

  - `ssh://[user@]server/project.git`
  - Shorter SCP-like syntax - `[user@]server:project.git`
- Git protocol - Starts with `git://`

GitHub has [dropped support for all **unencrypted** protocols](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/), which only includes the Git protocol (those that uses the `git://` prefix). Thus, the `The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.` error confirms this.

The way to mitigate this is by searching for the string `git://` within your `package.json` and lockfiles (e.g. `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`) to identify the offending package(s), and upgrade them to a version that does not use dependencies that resolves to a URL with the `git://` prefix. If the offending package is not in your `package.json`, you may find it helpful to run a command like [`yarn why`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why) to understand why the package is installed.

If that's not possible, and the repository is public, a temporary solution would be to manually replace `git://` with `https://`. But this solution is not permanent and may get overwritten the next time the lockfile is written to.

Answer (score 7):

Change `git://github.com/<blah>` to `git@github.com:<blah>` (note the `/` → `:` at the end) in your repository's .git/config file.

In my repository's .git/config file I had this line

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

which I changed to

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:curlconverter/curlconverter.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

and stopped getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

When all of the other solutions don't help, try editing your global config and removing all `instead of` declarations.

`git config --global --edit`

Comment: only answer that worked for me. My config was littered with all the insteadOf commands from everybody

Answer (score 2):

Add the code into ~/.gitconfig:

[url "https://"]

```
    insteadOf = ssh://
```

[url "https://"]

```
    insteadOf = git://
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this issue while running something like `pip install git+git://github.com/SomeCompany/somerepo.git@sometag`, then only the second part of `git+git` needs to change, i.e. it becomes `pip install git+https://github.com/SomeCompany/somerepo.git@sometag`

Answer (score 1):

Hello try the below options - this one worked for me

```
git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf git://github
```

Now git hubwont support unauthenticated git protocol
https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

I was getting the bellow error

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
warning: templates not found /tmp/pacote-git-template-tmp/git-clone-a001527f
fatal: remote error:
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/jquery/sizzle.git' into submodule path '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-19674e32/src/sizzle' failed
Failed to clone 'src/sizzle'. Retry scheduled
warning: templates not found /tmp/pacote-git-template-tmp/git-clone-a001527f
```

Comment: Yes, you will see the same git config line in [my answer two month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70663683/6309).