# Could not connect to MongoDb : openidconnect strategy requires an issuer option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, meanjs

im a fresher Nodejs developer,and i have some problems for which i really want to ask you all.
Im trying to setup a MEANJS project base on  : [meanjs](https://github.com/meanjs/mean), but there is some error occured unexpectedly on my process.
I was success to config this project on my PC (using window 10) yet,but when i try to config it on my laptop using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS,it start messed up.
For additional information on my system : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS , Nodejs 14x,npm 6x,Mongodb 4.4
Thanks all for help :D
Error :

```
Could not connect to MongoDB!
TypeError: OpenIDConnectStrategy requires an issuer option
    at Strategy (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/node_modules/passport-openidconnect/lib/strategy.js:31:32)
    at new Strategy (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/node_modules/passport-paypal-openidconnect/lib/passport-paypal-openidconnect/strategy.js:60:25)
    at module.exports (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/modules/users/server/config/strategies/paypal.js:11:16)
    at /home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/modules/users/server/config/users.server.config.js:31:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/modules/users/server/config/users.server.config.js:30:78)
    at /home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/config/lib/express.js:135:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.initModulesConfiguration (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/config/lib/express.js:134:31)
    at Object.module.exports.init (/home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/config/lib/express.js:246:8)
    at /home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/config/lib/app.js:25:23
    at /home/thangzjm_99/Code/WebUngLuong/config/lib/mongoose.js:35:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I really want to make my project run :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with older version of node. Meanjs is not maintained anymore. You probably encountered error while running `npm i` too.

Uninstall current version of node and install node v12.

Also github no logner support git protocol. so you may encounter more error

```
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/snyk/node-https-proxy-agent.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Connection timed out
```

can be solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70663683/13663683).