# how to install pyshpgeocode from git

Tags: python, git, pyshp

I would like to install the following from Git
https://github.com/vis4/pyshpgeocode

I tried the following command line found in StackOverflow but doesn't work

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git
```

Thank you very much for your help

F

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70663523/7976758

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git
cd pyshpgeocode/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: You don't need to clone the repo manually. `pip install git+https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git`. Otherwise, you won't be able to see the package in `pip list`, uninstall it, use it in `requirements.txt`, or other pip-associated operations.