# fatal: fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.comgithub.com[0: 20.205.243.166]]: errno=Operation timed out

Tags: git

I try to  clone a open source code but  I can't  finish it.

niesong@niesongdeiMac testApp % git clone https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.git
is cloning 'IQKeyboardManager'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.205.243.166]: errno=Operation timed out

this is my gitconfig

[url "“https://”"]
insteadOf = git://

[url "https://"]
insteadOf = git://

[url "git://github.com/"]
insteadOf = https://github.com/

but I can pod search IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I can  ping github.com
PING github.com (192.168.90.91): 56 data bytes64 bytes from 192.168.90.91: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=31.900 ms

Comment: 192.168 is part of the private network space: that's a machine on your own internal network, not GitHub. Looks like whoever's doing name service is redirecting you to some sort of proxy, probably a proxy that doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

`git://` protocol [is no longer supported at Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70663683/7976758). You should remove the section from your config:

```
git config --remove-section url.git://github.com/
```