# Unable to fetch Linux repository

Tags: git, github

Fairly easy question. Why am I unable to clone this Linux repository which does exist?

```
$ git clone git://github.com/nxp-auto-linux/linux;protocol=https;branch=release/bsp36.0-5.15.85-rt
Cloning into 'linux'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Connection timed out
```

When doing this it hangs for a couple of minutes and then I get the fatal error and the error saying the connection timed out.
Unless I am mistaken this branch and repo do exist

Comment: GitHub [removed support for the `git://` protocol](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) back in 2021. Use an https or ssh URL instead.

Comment: @larsks very problematic. [this is my situation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-April/018952.html). I tried fixing that, but athough the protocol was already set to http I tried replacing the prefix git to http, but that didn't work either as it thinks it is not a git repo. Cf [here](https://pastebin.com/jjZWaQet). I commented line 13 and added 14 and 15

Comment: Esp. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666585/7976758

Comment: @phd why did you downvote Daniel's answer? His answer is what is explained in the link you commented, unless I am mistaken

Comment: @ohiliouh I didn't. Please don't accuse people of things they haven't done!

Comment: It looks like this was an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you're asking about cloning using the git CLI -- and the comments here apply to that situation -- but according to your email to which you've linked you're actually using a different tool that interprets git URLs differently. You need to ask about the *actual* problem you're trying to solve; if you don't do that, you'll get answers that aren't necessarily applicable.

Comment: @larsks yhea, I know, my bad. It's just that this is so specific that it is highly unlikely I get a reply. Many questions about yocto are unanswered. I hoped the answer here would solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it doesn't work for you, however, your command also didn't work for me.

`git clone -b "release/bsp36.0-5.15.85-rt" git@github.com:nxp-auto-linux/linux` however did work fine.