# clone a github repo to a live site but getting: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, github, dreamhost, ssh-keys

I'm trying to get my github repo cloned on my live site for the first time.

I pushed my public key out to my dreamhost server's home directory from my local terminal like so:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@myserver.com 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

This didn't cause any errors and i can see my key on the remote server but when I try to clone a github repo after sshing into my remote server with:

```
git clone git@github.com:gituser/myrepo.git myserver.com/mysite
```

I get:

```
Cloning into mysite...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can push files from my local to github just fine (after a day of tweaking ;) ).

How do I clone from github to my remote server (live site)?

Comment: This answer should help you out.

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/88562/816157][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/88562/816157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to push the public key of your remote server to github.  If you haven't already generated the key, start at step one, https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.  Otherwise, start from step 4 where it shows you how to add the key to your github account.

Comment: Figured it out. this is correct but I didn't know I needed a separate ssh key for the remote server as well as my local and that they both needed to be entered into github. So I ran the steps you have listed above on my remote by ssh'ing in and copied that id_rsa.pub contents into github. btw... pbcopy didn't seem to work for me for ssh, just did it manually.